How meta-heuristic algorithms handle constraints
What I would like to ask is how constraints are handled in metaheuristic algorithms. For example, solving a multi-objective LRP problem using NSGA-II uses some kind of coding to represent both the siting decision and the path decision. But both warehouses and vehicles have capacities. Both constraints may be violated when performing the encoding. I'm thinking of three solution methods, so the big boys can see if they are feasible
Add penalty. Initially the solution is penalised for not satisfying the constraints. But how to deal with the situation where an objective value is related to both constraints and one is not.
Fix. After initialising the population, crossover, mutation, etc., repair operations are performed on the solution.
During initialisation, crossover, mutation, if an infeasible solution is generated, it is continued until a solution is generated that satisfies the constraints
And are there any books, videos, courses recommended in this area? On heuristic algorithms constraint handling
Add penalty. Initially the solution is penalised for not satisfying the constraints. But how to deal with the situation where an objective value is related to both constraints and one is not.
Fix. After initialising the population, crossover, mutation, etc., repair operations are performed on the solution.
During initialisation, crossover, mutation, if an infeasible solution is generated, it is continued until a solution is generated that satisfies the constraints
